# parseInt() & radix basics

Tags: javascript, parseint, radix, number-systems

Can someone please explain what radix is (on the most fundamental level), in reference to parseInt()?

I'm also not understanding how the string argument changes with different bases/radix.

Comment: `parseInt()`? *What* `parseInt()`? Which language? Which framework? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In JavaScript, and I'm just testing in the console atm to try and understand the radix component of it. Eg. why is parseInt(10761, 4) // 4 , whereas parseInt(10761, 8) // 4593

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the language you are using, here is an attempt at a general explanation:

> The radix is the **base of a numeral system**.

Decimal system: radix is 10,
therefore 100<sub>10</sub> means 100.

Binary system: radix is 2,
therefore 100<sub>2</sub> means 4.

---

This is why `parseInt(number, radix)` needs to know the radix you are working with, so that

```
parseInt(100, 2)
```

correctly yields `4` if you're in binary and

```
parseInt(100, 10)
```

correctly yields `100` in decimal.

---

Recommended Reading: [Number Systems and Bases](https://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/)